# If I mock an Angular component, how can I prevent the original component from being used?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, canvasjs

I'm trying to mock an Angular component in a unit test, but the original component still gets used, the mock doesn't seem to work. I am testing `MainComponent` and want to mock `SubComponent`. Here's what I'm trying:

```
import { MockComponent } from 'ng-mocks';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { SubComponent } from '../shared/components/sub/sub.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';

describe('MainComponent', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<MainComponent>;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: MainComponent,
    declarations: [MainComponent, MockComponent(SubComponent)],
    imports: [FormsModule, MaterialModule, AgGridModule],
    providers: [],
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(spectator.component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

From what I understand, this should mock `SubComponent`, however, I'm getting this error:

`Cannot find module 'canvasjs' from 'sub.component.ts'` (SubComponent imports CanvasJS)

If SubComponent is mocked, then the file sub.component.ts should not be accessed at all by these tests, right? How can I mock SubComponent so that no code from that component is being accessed?

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to ultimately test? I just want to see if we can create a shallow test where you don't use the factory. Perhaps you can new up the component and/or spy on it.

Comment: @Maccurt The MainComponent is a page that shows some CanvasJS plots, and the logic for the plots is in SubComponent. What would the test look like without the factory? Where would I declare MockComponent(SubComponent)?

Comment: @Maccurt Also, what do you mean by "new up the component"?

Comment: For the most part I try to stay away from test where you use the createComponentFactory. In my mind you are writing a unit test that is going to test one method. You can easily write "let component = new MainComponent(service)" and add your own mocks/stubs in the constructor and then assert on the method you are trying to test. You can spy and provide your own fake methods for the dependencies in the constructor. At the end of the day your Angular Components are just classes that you can do normal JS testing on..

Comment: Rather than importing SubComponent, you could also just define a component class in your spec file that has the same selector as SubComponent, as well as any Inputs and Outputs that MainComponent uses to interact with it. Add that mock component to your declarations array and your tests will use that as SubComponent.